# ascx user control when it's been registered on aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

Hi I've registered a user control on the top of an appx control.

```
<%@ Register Src="../Controls/Attachments.ascx" TagName="Attachments" TagPrefix="uc7" %>
<%@ Register Src="../Controls/Help.ascx" TagName="Help" TagPrefix="uc8" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/WRControls/WRDetails.ascx" TagName="WR" TagPrefix="uc9"  %>
```

Unfortunately when I try to call the new user control. i.e

"`<uc9:WR"` (uc9:WR does not appear in the ittelisense drop down) for the new user control which I've added.

The base user control is under a different file path to other user controls. As you can see above.

As i'm unable to find the user control in the intellisense I can then not add the control to the aspx page.

I've tried all sorts onthe base control i.e deleting all code in the designer.cs page then cutting and re-pasting the html to re-generate the designer.cs page all to no avail.

Comment: Personally, I've found Intellisense to be flakey with registered user controls. Does it compile and run without errors?

Comment: Try restart visual studio once again.

Comment: Just because intellisense isn't working right doesn't mean you can't add the control.  Intellisense is just there to try and make it easier, you can still hand type things.

Answer (score 0):

Register your user control in the web.config file as shown in this article:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx

Under `<pages>` in the web.config file, add a `<controls>` block as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

  <system.web>

    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="scottgu" src="~/Controls/Header.ascx" tagName="header"/>
        <add tagPrefix="scottgu" src="~/Controls/Footer.ascx" tagName="footer"/>
        <add tagPrefix="ControlVendor" assembly="ControlVendorAssembly"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>

  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: You probably know by now that answers with only a link are considered low quality. The link can change or die and then where are other users left? Staring at your [once useful] answer with nothing but frustration and tears in their eyes...