# ASPX User controls not usable whether registered on page or in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've tried Registering my user controls on the page as follows:

```
<%@Register Src="path_to_usercontrol.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" Tagname="control" %>
```

I've also tried registered my user controls on the web.config [per this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13383808/475766):

```
<pages>
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="uc" src="~/UserControls/ContractUserControl.ascx" tagName="Contract" />
    </controls>
</pages>
```

In theory, both approaches should absolutely work, however, neither does.

Per the linked question, Intellisense doesn't show me that a `"uc"` namespace exists in the first place let alone that the controls I want to use exist there.

I've tried cleaning and buidling/rebuilding both the project and the solution but none of this seems to affect the problem in any way whatsoever.

None of the documentation I've seen has indicated that I've done anything wrong or that I've left anything out, so what am I supposed to do to fix this problem?

#### Edit

I went 1 step further with this cleaning thing and deleted the Bin folder and web.config files from my project folder. The idea was to more thoroughly clean the Solution per @chrisrogers comment on [this answer about what Clean/Build/Rebuild do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3095935/475766).

Even still, absolutely nothing has changed after a new build once this was done.

Answer (score 0):

You still have to create an instance of the Control in order for intellisense to find it.

```
<div>
    <uc:control runat="server" ID="WebUserControl1" />
</div>
```

Now you can access it in code behind with the ID of `WebUserControl1`